# Calculate $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln{(1+x^2)}-x^2}{x^4}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How does one calculate the following limit? $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln{(1+x^2)}-x^2}{x^4}$$
My initial thought was to write $\ln(1+x^2)$ as $\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{x^2}x^2$ which is equal to $1$ when $x$ approaches $0$, but this is not allowed as the bottom function $x^4$ also approaches zero. Is applying L'Hopital multiple times the solution? Or am I missing a trick to make my work easier in this case?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%c3%b4pital-rule-or-series-expansion

Comment: Applying L'Hospital once does the job.

Comment: Are you allowed to use series expansion? (I presume you're not)

Comment: @SineoftheTime technically I am allowed to do whatever I want. The exam I'm preparing for is based on multiple choice answers, and no solutions or proofs are requested at the end. I simply need the right answer. I would probably not have time for series expansion, but I wouldn't mind knowing how to apply that!

Comment: @J__n Then I'll write it in an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can apply l'Hospital, but once is enough.
First you can easily check that the conditions for l'Hospital are met, then differentiating the numerator and denominator once gives
$$
\frac{\frac{2x}{1+x^2}-2x}{4x^3}=\frac{2x-2x(1+x^2)}{4x^3(1+x^2)}=\frac{-2x^3}{4x^3(1+x^2)}\xrightarrow{x\to0}-\frac{1}{2}.
$$
Hence the limit is $-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Before applying L'Hopital rule substitute $t=x^2.$

Comment: Doesn't change anything at all.

Comment: It does change. You do not need to apply the chain rule for example.

Comment: Of course you do have to apply the chain rule still, as the argument of the $\log$ is still $1+t$ and not just $t$. It just a nice little coincident that the derivative of this argument is $1$, which doesn't however change the fact that you need to apply the chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $t=x^2.$ The limit becomes
$$\lim_{t\to 0^+}{\ln(1+t)-t\over t^2}$$ By application l'Hopital rule we get $${{1\over 1+t}-1\over 2t}=-{1\over 2(1+t)}\underset{t\to 0^+}{\longrightarrow} -{1\over 2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that $\log(1+t)\sim t-t^2/2$ when $x\to 0$, we have:
$$\frac{\log{(1+x^2)}-x^2}{x^4}\sim\frac{x^2-x^4/2-x^2}{x^4}\overset{x\to0}\longrightarrow-\frac{1}{2} $$

Answer (score 0):

$$L=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln{(1+x^2)}-x^2}{x^4}$$

Let $y=x^4$

$$L=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\ln{(1+\sqrt{y})}-\sqrt{y}}{y}$$

With "L-H Rule" , we get :
$$L=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{1/[{2\sqrt{y}(1+\sqrt{y})}]-1/[2\sqrt{y}]}{1}$$

$$L=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{1-(1+\sqrt{y})}{{2\sqrt{y}(1+\sqrt{y})}}$$

$$L=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{-\sqrt{y}}{{2\sqrt{y}(1+\sqrt{y})}}$$

$$L=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{-1}{{2(1+\sqrt{y})}}$$

$$L=-1/2$$